# Cannot login to several TeamCity instances on the same host at the same time

Tags: teamcity, instances

I am new to `TeamCity` and need to complete the following task: Install and run two TeamCity instances on single Windows machine. Build agents are installed on other machine.

I got both instances running (installed using instructions from [the bottom answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198414/96505) to the question [how can I run multiple instances of teamcity on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6267737/96505)) But the problem is I can't be logged in in 2 web interfaces at the same time.

As soon as I login in to the 2nd the 1st interface logs me out.
I heard that it's about cookies, and I need to make changes so the web interface url would be not `localhost:port#`, and this is done by modifying `<context>` attribute.
I have tried to change `<context path = "/smth">` and was expecting that now my web interface url will be `localhost:port/smth` - but that is not working.
Could some one help me here?

Comment: When you say `that's not working` does it not make any difference or is it doing something else that you consider is "not working". Any additional information you can give will help us to answer your problem.

Comment: Hi Simon, by not working I mean I an not able to open webinterface at all, after modifying a <context path >, I see message - link is broken, or 404 page not found.

Comment: at the moment I have 1st TeamCity Web ui at http://localhost:8081 and second at http://localhost:8082. But cookies are "ignoring" the port, and it's like I am linking to the same web ui. What I need is to change the path to each web ui to smthn like http://application1, and http://application2 - how would I do that?

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you want to run two TC servers on the same machine?  There may be alternatives to this.