# TeamCity vs Jenkins for small startup devshop working in javascript tenchologies

Tags: jenkins, teamcity

What is a good option for a continuous integration server for a small startup devshop?

We work in javascript technologies and make some hybrid apps, among other things.

I was looking into this issue, and came across Jenkins and TeamCity.

It seems like TeamCity is the way we'd prefer to go. I've read numerous blog posts about how TeamCity has a much smoother user experience and things just generally laid out with more clarity. With TeamCity we won't be going on too many a wild goose chase. But for the moment we're trying to skirt our expenses, too.

The free version of TeamCity comes with a server, and 3 build agents. The server delegates the tests to the agents. Is that enough for a small dev shop? I'm thinking probably, but what do I know. We need to test on two different platforms as well as web view (actually that considered maybe 5 platforms - chrome, firefox, safari, android, iOS).

What do you guys think, does a free TeamCity server have enough bandwidth to take on a small dev shop? We have 3-5 people working on a project at a time.

Please add any thoughts you may have about Jenkins vs TeamCity, too

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing your own build servers can end up being quite time consuming, and as such, expensive, even if the licence is free. You also need to remember that while the licence may be free, servers are not. I say this because if I were in your shoes, I would look into something like [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.com/plans) or [CodeShip](https://codeship.com/pricing-organizations).

It looks expensive compared to a free Teamcity licence, but you owe it to yourselves to atleast consider such an option. (There are others, those are two of the popular choices)

To answer the original question: I do believe that Teamcity will have the "bandwidth" to support your needs, but setup will take some time and effort.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention this, we already have a server. A little intel NUC

Comment: Interesting idea, that may just work :) But the idea behind the agents are that each agent runs on their own server, and to test on iOS you will need a mac agent

Comment: Ah yeah - a mac agent. As far as multiple agents, though, I read you can have them on the same server - as long as each one has its own distinct directory setups

Comment: but you won't really gain anything from that with a NUC, in that case I think you are better of with a single agent, as mentioned in the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789381/608642)